# Hamcrest library for date

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I have been looking around but I have not found anything useful.  Are there any 3rd party libraries that work with hamcrest that have extensive date matching?

Specifically I am looking for matchers along the lines of:

```
assertThat(myDate, is(withinMinutes(sourceDate, 10)));
assertThat(myDate, is(afterDate(sourceDate)));
assertThat(myDate, is(betweenDates(startDate, endDate)));
```

I wanted to see if there was anything out there before I rolled my own.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at Yoda Time, with this library it should be easy to implement these matcher

Comment: Is that a Jedi fork of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 3):

I've written a set of date matchers which look like what you're after. The source is here https://github.com/eXparity/hamcrest-date. An example of how to use the within matcher

```
assertThat(dateUnderTest, DateMatchers.within(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new Date()));
```

You can add it with maven adding this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.exparity</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-date</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think what you're linking here is actually what the poster is after, but to avoid the perception of self promotion it's a good idea to provide some examples in the answer of how this would work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, i've added an example

Answer (score 0):

You should try [fest-assert](http://fest.easytesting.org/), it is not compliant with hamcrest but IMHO it is superior to it ("more fluent").
For example with date :

```
@Test
public void is_between_date_assertions_examples() {

    // various usage of isBetween assertion,
    // Note that isBetween(2002-12-17, 2002-12-19) includes start date but end date :
    assertThat(theTwoTowers.getReleaseDate())
            // = 2002-12-18
            .isBetween(theFellowshipOfTheRing.getReleaseDate(), theReturnOfTheKing.getReleaseDate())
            .isBetween(parse("2002-12-17"), parse("2002-12-19")) // [2002-12-17, 2002-12-19[
            .isBetween("2002-12-17", "2002-12-19") // [2002-12-17, 2002-12-19[
            .isNotBetween("2002-12-17", "2002-12-18") // [2002-12-17, 2002-12-18[
            .isBetween("2002-12-17", "2002-12-18", true, true); // [2002-12-17, 2002-12-18]
}
```

The full example with date is [here](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/fest-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fest/assertions/examples/DateAssertionsExamples.java), the others are [there](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/fest-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/org/fest/assertions/examples).

Comment: both links are now invalid.